# How do I upper and sentence case with two buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons, one for upper case and another for sentence case, but the upper case button is not not working. My code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function firstLetterUpper(theString) {
  var newString = theString.toLowerCase().replace(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)/g, function(c) {
    return c.toUpperCase()
  });
  return newString;
}

function convertToSentenceCase() {
  var theString = document.testForm.theString.value;
  //alert(theString);
  var newString = firstLetterUpper(theString);
  //console.log("Converted: "+newString);
  document.getElementById('theString').value = newString;
}


function firstLetterUpper(theString) {
  var newString = theString.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\s*\w|[\.\!\?]\s*\w)/g, function(c) {
    return c.toUpperCase()
  });
  return newString;
}

function convertToSentenceCase1() {
  var theString = document.testForm.theString.value;
  //alert(theString);
  var newString = firstLetterUpper(theString);
  //console.log("Converted: "+newString);
  document.getElementById('theString').value = newString;
}
```

```html
<form name="testForm">
  <textarea name="theString" id="theString" cols="50" rows="5">converts text string to "sentence case" -- capitalizes the first letter of every sentence, and makes the rest lower case. helpful when you need to convert content that is in all caps.</textarea><br>
  <button onclick="convertToSentenceCase();return false;">Convert to Sentence Case</button>

  <button onclick="convertToSentenceCase1();return false;">Convert to Upper Case</button>
</form>
```

Comment: please tell me for title case which replace i use i have use this /\b\w/g but it not for itle case tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same name for both of your functions `firstLetterUpper`.

```js
function firstLetterUpper(theString) {
  var newString = theString.toLowerCase().replace(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)/g, function(c) {
    return c.toUpperCase()
  });
  return newString;
}

function convertToSentenceCase() {
  var theString = document.testForm.theString.value;
  //alert(theString);
  var newString = firstLetterUpper(theString);
  //console.log("Converted: "+newString);
  document.getElementById('theString').value = newString;
}


function firstLetterUpper1(theString) {
  var newString = theString.toLowerCase().replace(/(^\s*\w|[\.\!\?]\s*\w)/g, function(c) {
    return c.toUpperCase()
  });
  return newString;
}

function convertToSentenceCase1() {
  var theString = document.testForm.theString.value;
  //alert(theString);
  var newString = firstLetterUpper1(theString);
  //console.log("Converted: "+newString);
  document.getElementById('theString').value = newString;
}
```

```html
<form name="testForm">
  <textarea name="theString" id="theString" cols="50" rows="5">converts text string to "sentence case" -- capitalizes the first letter of every sentence, and makes the rest lower case. helpful when you need to convert content that is in all caps.</textarea><br>
  <button onclick="convertToSentenceCase();return false;">Convert to Sentence Case</button>

  <button onclick="convertToSentenceCase1();return false;">Convert to Upper Case</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you wanted. But to make a string uppercase you can use JavaScript's in-built toUpperCase() function.

If you change your function to this it works as expected.

```
function convertToSentenceCase1() {
  var theString = document.testForm.theString.value;
  //alert(theString);
  var newString = theString.toUpperCase();
  //console.log("Converted: "+newString);
  document.getElementById('theString').value = newString;
}
```